# PySpark to Azure SQL Database connection issue

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, azure-active-directory, azure-sql-database

I'm trying to connect to Azure SQL Database from Azure Synapse workspace Notebook using PySpark. Also I would like to use Active Directory integrated authentication. So what I've tried:

```
jdbc_df = spark.read \
        .format("com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.spark") \
        .option("url", "jdbc:sqlserver://my_server_name.database.windows.net:1433") \
        .option("database","my_db_name") \
        .option("dbtable", "my_table_or_query") \
        .option("authentication", "ActiveDirectoryIntegrated") \
        .option("encrypt", "true") \
        .option("hostNameInCertificate", "*.database.windows.net") \
        .load()
```

Also I've tried the same way but in different syntax

```
jdbcUrl = "jdbc:sqlserver://my_server_name.database.windows.net:1433;database=my_db_name;encrypt=true;trustServerCertificate=false;hostNameInCertificate=*.database.windows.net;loginTimeout=30;Authentication=ActiveDirectoryIntegrated"

 pushdown_query = "SELECT col1 FROM my_table_name"
 connectionProperties = {
   "driver" : "com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver"
 }
 df = spark.read.jdbc(url=jdbcUrl, table=pushdown_query)
 display(df)
```

And in both cases I get error

> IllegalArgumentException: KrbException: Cannot locate default realm

What I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally I have found the solution! First of all there should be created working **Linked service** to Azure SQL database in your Synapse Analytics that uses Authentication type "**System Assigned Managed Identity**". Than you can reference it in your PySpark Notebook. And don't be confused that method **getConnectionString** is used to get access token - it really returns not connection string but token.

```
jdbcUrl = "jdbc:sqlserver://my_server_name.database.windows.net:1433;database=my_db_name;encrypt=true;trustServerCertificate=false;hostNameInCertificate=*.database.windows.net;loginTimeout=30"

token=TokenLibrary.getConnectionString("AzureSQLLinkedServiceName")

pushdown_query = "(SELECT col1 FROM my_table_name) as tbl"
connectionProperties = {
 "driver" : "com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver",
 "accessToken" : token
}
df = spark.read.jdbc(url=jdbcUrl, table=pushdown_query, properties=connectionProperties)
display(df)
```

Comment: I am also having the same scenario where trying to connect Azure SQL from Azure Synapse spark. Tried as mentioned in your answer executing the statement token=TokenLibrary.getConnectionString("AzureSQLLinkedServiceName") and printing it. I am getting below error   
Py4JJavaError: An error while calling z:com.microsoft.azure.synapse.tokenlibrary.TokenLibrary.getConnectionString.
: com.microsoft.azure.synapse.tokenlibrary.POST failed with 'Bad Request' (400) and message: {"result":"DependencyError","errorId":"BadRequest","errorMessage":"[Code=, Target=, Message=].  Error Component : LSR"}

Comment: @NaveenKumar were you able to solve the 400 error. I am also getting the same issue.

Comment: Wow Maryan, don't know how to thank you. Was looking for this information since a week. Thanks a lot. 

There is no proper documentation for this.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the below code to read the data from Azure SQL Database using Python:

```
# define sql database parameters
jdbcHostname = "my_server_name.database.windows.net"
jdbcDatabase = "my_db_name"
jdbcPort = "1433"
username = "username"
password = "XXXXXXXXXX"
jdbcUrl = "jdbc:sqlserver://{0}:{1};database={2}".format(jdbcHostname, jdbcPort, jdbcDatabase)

# passing parameters in connection properties
connectionProperties = {
"user" : username,
"password" : password,
"driver" : "com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver"
}

# sample query
pushdown_query = "SELECT col1 FROM my_table_name"

# reading data 
df = spark.read.jdbc(url=jdbcUrl, table=pushdown_query, properties=connectionProperties)

# print data
display(df)
```

Comment: That's basically what I'm using, the only difference is that I want to use Active Directory integrated authentication, not SQL login.

Comment: could you first try with SQL login and it its working we can give AD login.

Comment: Just did, and it works! But still I would like to use AD authentication, because I'm using System Assigned Managed Identity in my Linked Service for that SQL database in Synapse pipelines which I'm going to use for running this script.

Comment: check and try this once - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/synapse-analytics/spark/data-sources/apache-spark-sql-connector#azure-active-directory-authentication